# Python Regex re.compile query

Tags: python, regex, list, python-re, findall

I'm trying to find get a list of required names from list of names using a regex query.

csv file:  FYI, I converted Countries from Capital to small letters
[image]

searchList:

```
['AU.LS1_james.aus',
'AU.LS1_scott.aus',
'AP.LS1_amanda.usa',
'AP.LS1_john.usa',
'LA.LS1_harsha.ind',
'LA.LS1_vardhan.ind',
'IECAU13_peter-tu.can',
'LONSA13_smith.gbp']
```

Format of the `searchList`: `[(region)(Category)]_[EmployeeName].[country]`
`(region)(Category)` is concatenated.

I'm trying to get a list of each group like this,

```
[
['AU.LS1_james.aus', 'AU.LS1_scott.aus'],
['AP.LS1_amanda.usa', 'AP.LS1_john.usa'],
['LA.LS1_harsha.ind', 'LA.LS1_vardhan.ind']
]
```

Using the following regex query: `\<({region}).*\{country}\>`

```
for region, country in regionCountry:
    query = f"\<({region}).*\{country}\>"
    r = re.compile(query)
    group = list(filter(r.match, searchList))
```

I tried  `re.search`  as well, but the  `group` is always  `None`

> FYI: I also tried this query in notepad++ find using regex functionality.
> [image: NOTEPAD++ query: <(AU.LS1).*.aus>]

Can Anyone Tell where it's going wrong in my script.? Thank you

Comment: `A(?:P\.LS1_(?:amanda|john)\.usa|U\.LS1_(?:james|scott)\.aus)|LA\.LS1_(?:harsha|vardhan)\.ind`

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

1. `split`
2. And a dictionary to group the entries:

**Data**

```
entries = ['AU.LS1_james.aus', 'AU.LS1_scott.aus', 'AP.LS1_amanda.usa', 'AP.LS1_john.usa', 'LA.LS1_harsha.ind', 'LA.LS1_vardhan.ind']
```

**Solution 1**: simple `dict` and `setdefault`

```
d = {}
for entry in entries:
    d.setdefault(entry.split('.',1)[0], []).append(entry)
```

**Solution 2**: `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for entry in entries:
    d[entry.split('.',1)[0]].append(entry)
```

**Result** is in `d.values()`

```
>>> list(d.values())

[['AU.LS1_james.aus', 'AU.LS1_scott.aus'],
 ['AP.LS1_amanda.usa', 'AP.LS1_john.usa'],
 ['LA.LS1_harsha.ind', 'LA.LS1_vardhan.ind']]
```

Comment: appreciate your responsiveness,  I see that you're creating a dictionary using the `.` but the `region` doesn't always have `.` And It is dynamic. I'll update the question for a Better understanding of this

Comment: @HarshaVardhan, Before even talking about code, what is the separator allowing to differentiate in each element of the 'search list' the grouping key and the rest of the element? If it's the `'_'` character then in my code `'.'` should be replaced by `'_'`.

Comment: you're right, the separator is `'_'` I've already tried to use the `.split` method, but the problem is some time the `.csv` file can have just `_` in or just '.' the latest data from the source is good, but the old corrupted data is the issue, and god knows what other single characters exist in that file. So instead of restricting the unwanted characters, 1 by 1 programmatically, I chose `regex` to only grab the data, which meets my criteria. I Appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

I thank you all for trying to assist my question. This answer worked out well for my usage. For some reason python doesn't like `\<` and `\>`. so i just removed them and it worked fine. I didn't expect that there could be some limitations using `re` library.

**Answer**:
`f({region}).*\{country}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).